# Is there any way to capture zoomed/brushed d3.js multi-line graph position?

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js

I've created a multi-line graph using d3.js with the functionalities of zoom and brush. All the functionalities are working fine except when I refresh my browser tab, the zoom/brush I've done in the graph gets reset and the graph gets displayed in it's initial state.
Is there any way I can record the zoom/brush position using any d3.js function and whenever I refresh my browser page, I could see the graph in it's last zoomed/brushed state.
Attaching the code snippet I am using for zoom and brush.

```
const brush = d3.brushX()
        .extent([[0, 0], [this.width, this.height2]])
        .on("brush end", () => {
          if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "zoom") {
            return;
          } // ignore brush-by-zoom
          const s = d3.event.selection || this.x2.range();
          this.x.domain(s.map(this.x2.invert, this.x2));
          legendDataLine.selectAll(".line").attr("d", (d: any) => line(d.values));
          focus.select(".axis--x").call(d3.axisBottom(this.x));
          this.svg.select(".zoom").call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
              .scale(this.width / (s[1] - s[0]))
              .translate(-s[0], 0));
        });

const zoom = d3.zoom()
        .scaleExtent([1, Infinity])
        .translateExtent([[0, 0], [this.width, this.height]])
        .extent([[0, 0], [this.width, this.height]])
        .on("zoom", () => {
          if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "brush") {
            return;
          } // ignore zoom-by-brush
          const t = d3.event.transform;
          this.x.domain(t.rescaleX(this.x2).domain());
          legendDataLine.selectAll(".line").attr("d", (d: any) => line(d.values));
          focus.select(".axis--x").call(d3.axisBottom(this.x));
          context.select(".brush").call(brush.move, this.x.range().map(t.invertX, t));
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method comes to mind, use a URL query string. In your example code, or the canonical brush and zoom example [here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172), only two parts of the zoom transform matter: the scale (`k`) and the `x` value.

We can record the `x` and `k` each zoom event and add them to or modify them in the URL query string. We don't need to worry about doing this in the brush events because the brush events trigger a zoom (and each zoom triggers a brush). To avoid endless loops, brush induced zoom events are ignored:

```
  if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "brush") return; // ignore zoom-by-brush
```

So, we can set the URL parameters before this is done:

```
function zoomed() {
  var t = d3.event.transform;
  // Update url:
  window.history.replaceState( {} , '', '?k='+t.k+"&x="+t.x )

  // ... rest of zoom functionality
}
```

This updates the query string and URL, and it does so without reloading the page, there are other options out that might offer better compatibility but are much less succinct  (this won't work with IE if I'm not mistaken). *As there are many better resources out there for methods to set the query string parameters, I won't go into that in any more detail here.*

Now we should have a stored the `x` and `k` values in the updated URL.

With the updated URL, reloading the page will load the page with the zoom state parameters in the address. All that's left is applying them on page load, if they are set of course.

After the data loads and everything is created, we can check to see if zoom parameters were provided in the URL and apply the appropriate zoom transform:

```
 var url = (new URL(document.location)).searchParams;
 if(url.has("k") && url.has("x")) {
   svg.select(".zoom").call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity.translate(+url.get("x"),0).scale(+url.get("k")));
 }
```

My retrieval of the URL is basic and again I'm not going to dwell on how I pull the parameters (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams) for more info on this method). If the `x` and `k` parameters are present, they're coerced to numbers and used to create a d3 zoom transform (using the d3.zoomIdentity as a base) and this is used to trigger a zoom event with the appropriate transform. By doing so, the zoom parameters stored in the URL are used to update the graph to its last state on reload, back, forward, or opening a link with the updated URL, etc.

As this probably won't work in a Stack Overflow snippet, I've created an example [here](https://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/raw/49d7645eb9454ceed583ccf4a86df299/?k=6.9644045063690045&x=-2951.920175516334).

Comment: Thanks man it really worked. Although, instead of query-params I used local storage, because I have multiple graphs in the same page.